# query in mongodb atlas to verify the existence of multiple specific documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoimport

I have a mongodb collection called employeeInformation, in which I have two documents:

```
{"name1":"tutorial1"}, {"name2":"tutorial2"}
```

When I do db.employeeInformation.find(), I get both these documents displayed. My question is - is there a query that I can run to confirm that the collection contains only those two specified documents? I tried db.employeeInformation.find({"name1":"tutorial1"}, {"name2":"tutorial2"}) but I only got the id corresponding to the first object with key "name1". I know it's easy to do here with 2 documents just by seeing the results of .find(), but I want to ensure that in a situation where I insert multiple (100's) of documents into the collection, I have a way of verifying that the collection contains all and only those 100 documents (note I will always have the objects themselves as text). Ideally this query should work in mongoatlas console/interface as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.collection.count()

will give you number of inserts once you have inserted the document.

Thanks,
Neha

Comment: but is there a way to confirm what the objects actually are? with my original query I was hoping for something like returning true if the specified objects inside the brackets were included in the collection. That in conjunction with .count() would verify that the insert worked successfully